# Moving button click event from protected accessor to public

Tags: asp.net

Created a button in my aspx file and add its click method in the in my cs file.

When i run the aspx file my button calls its click method, but when i remove the protected access modifier from its click method then it shows undefined method error.
Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this so?

Because when you remove the `protected` access modifier and you do not specify any other modifier, `private` is assumed, and click handlers cannot be private. They must at least be protected because ASP.NET generates at runtime a class that derives from the page you have defined and it needs to be able to call its base methods.